# Is it possible to do a path integral between two boundaries analytically on a quantum lattice?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, boundary-conditions, lattice-model

I have been trying to perform some path integral between two boundaries for a massless scalar field

$$\int_{\varphi(t_a, \vec{x})}^{\varphi(t_b, \vec{x})} \mathcal{D}\varphi(x)e^{iS[\varphi(x)]}$$

using lattice methods, but so far I am having trouble seeing if this leads anywhere.

The method used is the following. First, a Wick rotation to go to Euclidian space

$$\int_{\varphi(t_a, \vec{x})}^{\varphi(t_b, \vec{x})} \mathcal{D}\varphi(x)e^{-S_E[\varphi(x)]}$$

Followed by a transformation of the action into a lattice one (to simplify matters I am in two dimensions) :

$$S_E[\varphi(x)] = \frac{a^2}{2} \sum_{x,y\in\Bbb Z^2} \varphi(x) K_{xy} \varphi(y)$$

With $K_{xy}$ the standard matrix for lattice scalar fields, $$K_{xy} = -a^{-2} (\delta_{x + a (1,0), y} + \delta_{x + a (0,1), y} + \delta_{x - a (1,0), y} + \delta_{x - a (0,1), y} - 2 \delta_{xy})$$

So the integral becomes

$$\int \prod_{\substack{t = 1\\x\in \Bbb Z}}^N d\varphi_{t,x}\exp[\sum_{\substack{t=1 \\ x\in \Bbb Z}}^N -\varphi_{t,x}^2 + \frac{\varphi_{t,x}}{2}(\varphi_{t+1,x} + \varphi_{t-1,x} + \varphi_{t,x+1} + \varphi_{t,x-1})]$$

(Currently I didn't look for the normalization factor of the measure)

The terms depending on $\varphi_{1,0}$ are

$$ -\varphi_{1,0}^2 + \frac{\varphi_{1,0}}{2}(\varphi_{2,0} + \varphi_{0,0} + \varphi_{1,1} + \varphi_{1,-1}) + \frac{\varphi_{2,0}}{2}\varphi_{1,0} + \frac{\varphi_{0,0}}{2}\varphi_{1,0} + \frac{\varphi_{1,1}}{2}\varphi_{1,0} + \frac{\varphi_{1,-1}}{2}\varphi_{1,0} $$

giving me

$$ -\varphi_{1,0}^2 + \varphi_{1,0}(\frac{ \varphi_{0,0}}{2} + \varphi_{2,0} + \varphi_{1,1} + \varphi_{1,-1}) $$

Using the standard formula for integrating gaussians,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2 + bx} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}$$

The integral over $x = \varphi_{1,0}$ becomes

$$\int dx\exp[-x^2 + x(\frac{ \varphi_{0,0}}{2} + \varphi_{2,0} + \varphi_{1,1} + \varphi_{1,-1})] = \sqrt{\pi} \exp(\frac{1}{4}(\frac{ \varphi_{0,0}}{2} + \varphi_{2,0} + \varphi_{1,1} + \varphi_{1,-1})^2)$$

The same reasoning applies for $\varphi_{1,1}$, with the added terms from the previous integral (and removing the cross term with $\varphi_{1,0}$ which has already been integrated over) :

$$ -\varphi_{1,1}^2 + \varphi_{1,1}(\frac{ \varphi_{0,1}}{2} + \varphi_{2,1} + \varphi_{1,2}) + \frac{1}{4} (\varphi_{1,1}^2 + 2\varphi_{1,1} (\frac{ \varphi_{0,0}}{2} + \varphi_{2,0} + \varphi_{1,-1})) $$

Or

$$ -\frac{3}{4}\varphi_{1,1}^2 + \varphi_{1,1}(\frac{ \varphi_{0,1}}{2} + \varphi_{2,1} + \varphi_{1,2} + \frac{ \varphi_{0,0}}{4} +\frac{\varphi_{2,0}}{2} + \frac{\varphi_{1,-1}}{2})$$

Same integral, with result :

$$\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}} \exp(\frac{1}{3}(\frac{ \varphi_{0,1}}{2} + \varphi_{2,1} + \varphi_{1,2} + \frac{ \varphi_{0,0}}{4} +\frac{\varphi_{2,0}}{2} + \frac{\varphi_{1,-1}}{2})^2)$$

Unfortunately, unlike the lattice version of the path integral of a point particle, terms do not disappear as the integral goes along, at least for the integral over space. Every term remains, although I quite suspect they converge towards 0 as we get further and further away from $x=0$. And so far the integral over time has not even been attempted yet.

Is it possible to perform this integral in a way to get meaningful results? I suspect the key would be to know the series for the factors of the various terms. The only one I think I have is the contribution to the quadratic term, which changes due to the integral of the previous points :

$$ - a_i \varphi_i^2 \rightarrow (-1 + \frac{1}{4 a_i}) \varphi_{i+1}^2$$

a continued fraction starting as $-1, -\frac{3}{4}, -\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{5}{8}, -\frac{2}{5}, -\frac{5}{12} ...$. I think the other series for it are :

For the terms in the boundary $\varphi_{0,j}$ : 
$$a_i \varphi_i \frac{\varphi_{0,j}}{2^{2|i-j|}} \rightarrow (-1 + \frac{1}{4 a_i}) \varphi_{i+1}\frac{\varphi_{0,j}}{2^{2|i-j|+1}}$$

(Basically they just gain another factor of a half per integral)

Same with the terms that are not in the boundary, except that they do not start out with a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$.

I was somewhat hopeful that only terms immediatly next to the term being integrated would contribute, but apparently it is not so. Is it possible to perform this integral analytically, first over space, then over every slice of time in the integral, and obtain a reasonable quantity in the continuum limit (for instance, some kind of functional of $\varphi(t_a, \vec x)$ and $\varphi(t_b, \vec x)$)?

Obviously once integrated over every $\varphi(t, x)$, only terms of the boundary will remain, but so far I have no clue to what this would converge. I suspect that once integrated over all space at $t = 1$, I would get a term of the form

$$\propto \exp[((\sum_i \frac{a_i}{2^i})(\sum_i\frac{\varphi_{0,i}}{2} + \varphi_{2,i}))^2]$$

With $a_i$ the continued fraction.